# Using an UNLOAD statement in an Informix stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

I'm writing an Informix procedure.
I created a temp table, but I want to export this data in a text document.
I can't use an UNLOAD statement in SPL; can somebody help me?

Comment: Certainly, I want to unload this table to the disk. I call like that: ** execute procedure my_proce();**

Answer (score 3):

The UNLOAD statement is not recognized by the server.  The programs such as DB-Access, ISQL and I4GL recognize it and simulate it as a statement (basically, as a SELECT, of course, reading the data from the server and writing it to a file on the client).  Consequently, the statement won't work in SPL — Stored Procedure Language — because that is run by the server on the server.  (One reason for the disconnect is that the server can't write direct to a file on the client.)

So, you'll need to do things differently.  The solution suggested by [Ricardo Henriques](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4667815/ricardo-henriques) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31994275/15168) is entirely sensible, as long as the file being created on the server machine is OK.

Comment: If are you using IFX version >=11.70 (do not remember the fix), you can try use the UTL_FILE package, I will not post this as answer because I never use it , yet... maybe you can use it to save your data in TXT files . Check [here the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.dbext.doc/ids_r0053689.htm?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

Will you execute it on the **Informix Server** or a **client**? Which is the **IDS** version?

Here is a way using [external tables](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2084.htm?lang=en), the file is stored on the server host:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_unload()

    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1(
        col1 INT
    ) WITH NO LOG;

    INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES (1);
    INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES (2);
    INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES (3);

    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp1_ext 
    SAMEAS temp1
    USING (
        DATAFILES ("DISK:/home/informix/temp.dat") 
        );

    INSERT INTO temp1_ext SELECT * FROM temp1;

    DROP  TABLE temp1_ext;
    DROP  TABLE temp1;

END PROCEDURE;
```

If what you're looking is to store on a client server you'll have to provide what kind of client you use (**OS** and the way you connect to the **IDS**).

If your using the **dbaccess** you can use the **SP** to create the temporary table and after submit the `unload` of the data.

If using other clients probably your best option is to rewrite your **SP** as a [function that returns more than one value from more than one row.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_465.htm?lang=en).

Then, iterate it and write to a file.