# How to prevent line breaks in long text value returned from an Informix stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, informix

I am writing a stored procedure that simulates an Informix UNLOAD so that I get the output into a pipe-delimited text file for transfer to another system. My procedure works as expected, but when I redirect the output to a text file in my shell script, the lines are breaking after 66 characters. I need each record to be on its own line with no line breaks in the record.

The text string that it returns for each record could be as long as 350 characters. Is there an Informix setting that is causing this to happen? Something in my shell script?

The entire procedure is included below. I have also added code that shows how I am calling this SP from the shell script.

We are using Solaris 10 and Informix IDS 11.70.

I saw the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992388/using-an-unload-statement-in-an-informix-stored-procedure/31994275#31994275) to an SO question about doing UNLOAD in stored procedures before. For now, the preference is to avoid using a temp table and an external table. (But we may go back to that solution if we can't get this approach to work.)

```sh
# Real script receives these as args or calculates using today's date
begin_date="2019-04-26 00:00:00"
end_date="2019-04-26 23:59:59"
dbname="mydatabase"
STORED_PROCEDURE="sp_unload_mytable"
OUTFILE="return.dat"

rm -f $OUTFILE
echo "execute procedure ${STORED_PROCEDURE}('${begin_date}','${end_date}') " | dbaccess $dbname \
| sed 's,(expression),,' | sed 's/,$//' | sed -e '/^$/d' | sed 's/^[ ]*//' > $OUTFILE
```

```sql
create procedure sp_unload_mytable(start_date datetime year to second, end_date datetime year to second)
   returning lvarchar(500);

   DEFINE p_rep_serial      integer;
   DEFINE p_post_flag       integer;
   DEFINE p_recording_date  varchar(8);
   DEFINE p_lastname        varchar(35);
   DEFINE p_firstname       varchar(20);
   DEFINE p_middlename      varchar(20);
   DEFINE p_generation      varchar(4);
   DEFINE p_role        varchar(8);
   DEFINE p_corporperson    varchar(1);
   DEFINE p_party_type      varchar(1);
   DEFINE p_b           varchar(5);
   DEFINE p_p           varchar(4);
   DEFINE p_item_number     varchar(4);
   DEFINE p_i_code          varchar(3);
   DEFINE p_i_desc          varchar(10);
   DEFINE p_par_id      varchar(12);
   DEFINE p_ref_b               varchar(5);
   DEFINE p_ref_p           varchar(4);
   DEFINE p_remark_1        varchar(20);
   DEFINE p_remark_2        varchar(20);
   DEFINE p_i_id            varchar(10);
   DEFINE p_ret_code        varchar(12);
   DEFINE p_nbr_of_attempts varchar(12);
   DEFINE p_insert_timestamp    datetime year to second;
   DEFINE p_edit_flag       varchar(12);
   DEFINE p_document_id     varchar(12);
   DEFINE p_version     varchar(6);
   DEFINE p_attempts        varchar(6);
   DEFINE p_return      lvarchar(500);

   FOREACH SELECT rep_serial, post_flag, nvl(recording_date, ""),
        nvl(lastname, ""), nvl(firstname, ""), nvl(middlename, ""), 
        nvl(trim(generation), ""), nvl(trim(role), ""), 
        nvl(trim(corporperson), ""), nvl(trim(party_type), ""), 
                  nvl(trim(b), ""), nvl(trim(p), ""), nvl(trim(item_number), ""), 
                  nvl(trim(i_code), ""), nvl(trim(i_desc), ""), 
                  nvl(par_id, ""), nvl(trim(ref_b), ""), 
                  nvl(trim(ref_p), ""), nvl(remark_1, ""), nvl(remark_2, ""), 
                  nvl(i_id, ""), nvl(ret_code, ""), nvl(nbr_of_attempts, ""), 
                  nvl(insert_timestamp, ""), nvl(edit_flag, ""), nvl(document_id, ""), 
                  nvl(version, ""), nvl(attempts, "")
        INTO p_rep_serial, p_post_flag, p_recording_date, p_lastname, p_firstname, 
             p_middlename, p_generation, p_role, p_corporperson, p_party_type, 
             p_b, p_p, p_item_number, p_i_code, p_i_desc, 
             p_par_id, p_ref_b, p_ref_p, p_remark_1, 
             p_remark_2, p_i_id, p_ret_code, p_nbr_of_attempts, 
             p_insert_timestamp, p_edit_flag, p_document_id, p_version, p_attempts
        from mytable
        where insert_timestamp between start_date and end_date

        LET p_return = p_rep_serial || "|" || p_post_flag || "|" || p_recording_date || "|" || p_lastname || "|" || p_firstname || "|" || p_middlename || "|" || p_generation || "|" || p_role || "|" || p_corporperson || "|" || p_party_type || "|" || p_b || "|" || p_p || "|" || p_item_number || "|" || p_i_code || "|" || p_i_desc || "|" || p_par_id || "|" || p_ref_b || "|" || p_ref_p || "|" || p_remark_1 || "|" || p_remark_2 || "|" || p_i_id || "|" || p_ret_code || "|" || p_nbr_of_attempts || "|" || p_insert_timestamp || "|" || p_edit_flag || "|" || p_document_id || "|" || p_version || "|" || p_attempts;

        RETURN p_return WITH RESUME;

   END FOREACH;

end procedure;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's DB-Access that's causing the trouble.

If you were using a sufficiently recent version of Informix (12.10.xC12 or 14.10.xC1 or later within each of those families of versions), you could use the environment variable `DBACCESS_COLUMNS` to set the effective width of the 'screen' (output).  However, if the data itself contains newlines, then those will be reflected in the output.  Other than by coercing the output to JSON (which ain't particularly easy, but you can look up [`genBSON`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2311.htm) if you're curious), I don't know of a way to remove newlines or replace them with `\n` or similar, other than by post-processing the DB-Access output.

Since your version of Informix (11.70) is too old to support `DBACCESS_COLUMNS`, I'm not sure there's a really good alternative.

At a pinch, you could use my [SQLCMD](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL) program (no relation to Microsoft's johnny-come-lately interloper of the same name).  To obtain it there, you'd have to join the IIUG (International Informix Users Group), which is free and doesn't involve too many emails (a couple a month unless you subscribe to any of the mailing lists).  The advantage of SQLCMD over DB-Access is that it automatically does 'as wide as necessary' output, but it doesn't have an output mode for "do not include newlines directly" except via it's JSON-style output (which I see I need to bug-fix in v91.03, which is more recent than what's on the IIUG web site — it isn't a sufficiently useful option just at the moment).  I'll consider adding a 'C-style escapes output' option (or maybe it'll just be JSON-style, since I need to handle JSON better anyway — TBD).  SQLCMD should compile OK with just about any version of Informix (ESQL/C) that you can lay your hands on.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for the quick response and the helpful information. The system should be upgrading to Informix 12.1 later this year. For now, we'll find another solution.